# Зачем нужен MAC-адрес если есть ip?

Tags: сеть, ip, ethernet, arp, mac-address

Преподаватель задал вопрос: зачем нужен mac адрес если есть ip. Я имею в виду ситуацию когда прежде, чем подключится к одному из устройств IP-протокол проверяет, есть ли в его ARP-таблице запись о соответствующем устройстве. Если запись есть, то происходит передача пакетов. Если же нет, то посылается широковещательный ARP-запрос, который выясняет какому устройству принадлежит IP-адрес. Определив себя, устройство посылает в ответ свой MAC адрес и он заносится в таблицу.
Так вот собственно вопрос зачем нужен MAC адрес, почему IP адреса недостаточно?

Comment: Потому что в физической сети (если быть точным в ethernet и некоторых других физических сетях) адресация устройств происходит исключительно по mac адресу. Тем более что по сети можно передавать не только IP пакеты но и пакеты других протоколов в которых понятия IP в принципе не существует

Comment: Потому что IP это адресация в сети - аналогия телефонного номера закрепленного за квартирой, звонить может каждый и с разного телефона, а вот MAC это конкретно кто снимает трубку и какого телефона.

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak а что если за каждым человеком закрепить номер мобильного телефона?) аналогии работают только в детективах.

Answer (score -1):

Чтоб передать тот же IP через роутер. Хоть и FDB таблицу на коммутаторах можно заполнить IP адресами, без мака роутеру пришлось бы знать все адреса, что стоят за ним чтоб получить ответ.